# How do I get the "Say Hi to the Internet" achievement?

Tags: achievements, far-cry-3

Just finished up the main storyline for Far Cry 3 and I'm trying to mop up some achievements. I haven't the slightest idea what I'm supposed to be doing for this one though. The description just says "Find the Lost Hollywood Star." Has anyone found this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lost Hollywood star can be found at the coordinates X: 619.7, Y: 559.4 (see top right corner of the world map). This is at the beach of one of the northern islands. You can go there shortly after the game starts. Stay at the beach and look for two dead people that are hanging on a tree. There is a man burried in the sand and you can only see his head. Go to the burried man and press Square.

[Source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/far-cry-3/achievement/73273-Say-Hi-to-the-Internet.html)

Comment: Although in game the head is not his likeness, it's meant to be the head of Christopher Mintz-Plasse. For back story watch The Far Cry Experience videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avmQTr5Kr3A